# Webpack Install Error

Tags: webpack, installation

I am working on Ubuntu and I keep getting this error! Please help!

```
skudari@skudari:~/Website$ sudo npm install webpack@3.0.0 --save-dev
```

> WARN engine webpack@3.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"}
>   (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"}) WARN engine webpack@3.0.0:
>   wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"} (current: {"nloadDep:yargs
>   → resolveWi
>
> WARN engine enhanced-resolve@3.3.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 ||
>
> > =5.10"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"}) WARN engine loader-runner@2.3.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"}
> >     (currenloadDep:yargs → afterAdd
>
> WARN engine uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0
>   <5.0.0 || >=5.10my-awesome-package@1.0.0 /home/skudari └──
>   react@15.6.1  extraneous
>
> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency
>   /chokidar/fsevents: npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating
>   system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2 npm WARN
>   my-awesome-package@1.0.0 No description npm WARN
>   my-awesome-package@1.0.0 No repository field. npm WARN
>   my-awesome-package@1.0.0 No license field.

Answer (score 0):

Your Node.js version is `4.2.6`, but the package you're trying to install (`webpack`) requires at least version `4.3.0`. Many packages specify a minimum Node.js version because they need some features that have been added in a certain version or there were some bugs/issues in some of the versions, which negatively affected the package.

You should upgrade your Node version, especially since version 4 is no longer actively maintained, which means that only *critical* fixes are applied, until it reaches the end of life (for details see [LTS schedule](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS#lts-schedule1)).

You can follow the instructions for installing it with Ubuntu's package manger: [Debian and Ubuntu based Linux distributions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions).

Or you can use a version manager like [`n`](https://github.com/tj/n) or [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install the desired version.

```sh
# The latest version, currently v8.1.4
n latest
# The long term supported version, currently v6.11.1
n lts
```